# Hypergeometric Simplification Intuition

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

[image]

For the final inequality, could someone explain the intution behind the $M-(N-K)\leq x$? I am struggling to find an intuitive argument for this relationship. Like if we have $N=20$ balls and $M=15$ are red, then the difference between the number of red balls and the number of total balls that remain after choosing $K$ must be less than the number of reds that we chose.

Comment: It's simpler than that. One half of the inequality says you can't draw more red balls than there are; the other says you can't draw more green balls than there are.